# Pandas check multiple rows and copy a different row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've this following scenario.

Table 1

```
column_a column_b 
1         10
2         20
3         30
4         40
```

Table 2

```
column_a new_column 
1         10
2         20
3         30
5         0
```

If **values in column_a in both tables match**, **the new_column should be populated with corresponding value from table 1 column_b. If not, 0 should be populated**.

I could do this using iterrows on both the tables, but is there any better/efficient way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `map` + `fillna`

```
df2['new_col'] = df2.column_a.map(df1.set_index('column_a').column_b).fillna(0)

print(df2)
   column_a  new_col
0         1     10.0
1         2     20.0
2         3     30.0
3         5      0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.where`

```
df2.new_column = np.where(df1.column_a.eq(df2.column_a), df1.column_b, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is merge:

```
df2.merge(df, on='column_a', how='left')

   column_a  column_b
0         1      10.0
1         2      20.0
2         3      30.0
3         5       NaN

# add replace and rename if you want

df2.merge(df, on='column_a', how='left').replace(np.nan, 0).rename(columns={'column_b':'new_column'})

   column_a  new_column
0         1        10.0
1         2        20.0
2         3        30.0
3         5         0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

After having your module imported and your table1 and table2 constructed. You probably need something like this
`mask = table1['column_a']==table2['column_a'] 
table2.loc[mask,'new_column']= table1.loc[table1['column_a']==table2['column_a'],'column_b']
table2.loc[~mask,'new_column'] = 0`
 Notice that table1 and table2 are constructed by 
`import pandas as pd
table1 = pd.DataFrame({'column_a':[1,2,3,4],'column_b':[10,20,30,40]})
table2 = pd.DataFrame({'column_a':[1,2,3,5]})`